# Counting digit occurrences

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, digits, counting

This problem is really confusing me; we're given two integers **A**, **B**, we want to count occurrences of digits in the range **[A, B]**. I though that if we could count the number of digit occurrences in the range **[0, A]** and **[0, B]**, then the rest is trivial. So how can I count digit occurrences in a range **[0, x]**?
This isn't homework, this is actually a problem from SPOJ.
The naive approach won't work, as A and B can be as large as 10 ^ 9. Here are some examples:

**Input:**

1 10

**Output:**

1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

**Input:**

44 497

**Output:**

85 185 185 185 190 96 96 96 95 93

Comment: Do you know how to count digit occurrences in a single number?

Comment: We need a bit more information here.  Sample data sets and what the corresponding answer is would be nice.  Have you tried to solve the problem and have issues with code? If so, please post what you have.  Is this homework?  Tag as such

Comment: Well if the range is huge this is pretty interesting actually.

Comment: Mathematically your assumption is correct. In computing it is a bad idea though. Think about this example: A=10^10^10^10 and B=10^10^10^10+1.

Comment: For `1`s, see: http://oeis.org/A094798 There even is Maple code there!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try the brute force approach first to get something working.  Look at each number, iterate through each character in the string representation of that number, etc.

However, there is an easier way.

- In the interval [0,9], 3 appears 1 time
- In the interval [0,99], 3 appears 10 times in the first digit and 10 times in the second digit
- In the interval [0,999], 3 appears 100 times in the first digit, 100 times in the second digit and 100 times in the third digit.

You can generalize this and with a bit of effort come up with a formula for how many of a certain digit (0 being a possible special case) will appear in a certain range.  You don't need to actually go through each number.

Comment: (As long as you note that it appears 10 times on the left and 10 times on the right for a total of 29 times!)

Comment: This won't really help, will it? The ranges you specified are "special", they are all equal to 10 ^ x - 1 for some x.

Comment: @Abody97 Right, but very large ranges will include a lot of these special ones, saving a lot of computation time..

Comment: @Abody97 you can do this recursively on the digits. E.g, for 32554, do 30000, then 2000, then 500, 50, 4.

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha is your friend (at least upon some number near 21 * 10^4):

```
Input:

44 497

Output:

85 185 185 185 190 96 96 96 95 93
```

[**Try Me**](http://tinyurl.com/6gtvqw5)

Result:

**{85, 185, 185, 185, 188, 96, 96, 96, 95, 93}**

Comment: Not so friendly anymore: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Rotateleft%28%23[[2]]%26%2F%40%28%28Tally%40Flatten[IntegerDigits%2F%40Range[1000000000]]+%29-%28Tally%40Flatten[IntegerDigits%2F%40Range[44]]+%29%29%2C9%29

Comment: @IVlad The free usage is friendly up to a certain threshold. For more friendliness, you ought to pay them. Rep points not allowed as bitcoins, sorry :)

Comment: I don't think it's about paying them. I'm not too proficient in mathematica, but it looks like it's iterating over every number in the given range and counting the digits, which is hopelessly slow and which the OP clearly specified won't work. And yet here we have 2 posts suggesting the naive method...

Answer (score -1):

With problems of this kind, it's often useful to start with a slow-and-ugly implementation before working out how to do it properly and fast. You might learn something about the structure of the problem, and you can use the slow implementation to test the correctness of the fast one.

In Python, for example, you might write the slow version like this (it's not necessarily the best way to do it, but it's among the shortest...)

```python
>>> A, B = 1, 100
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(''.join(map(str, range(A, B + 1))))
Counter({'1': 21, '3': 20, '2': 20, '5': 20, '4': 20,
         '7': 20, '6': 20, '9': 20, '8': 20, '0': 11})
```